# How is MySQL encoding the general.log

Tags: mysql, unicode, logging

My MySQL 5.7 is running on UTF8

```
mysql> show variables like 'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and for debugging puposes I switched the general log on

```
[mysqld]
general_log = on
general_log_file=/tmp/general.log
```

Now I'm seeing not correct encoded values inside general.log.

```
 file /tmp/general.log 
/tmp/general.log: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

When searching for Rätsel (German Umlaut ä; ä) I can see inside logs  `R�tsel` (with broken Umlaut).

When having a look with an hexeditor, it appers like

```
27 2B 52 EF BF BD 74 73 65 6C 20 20 27
```

Heyedit shows it as  `'+R...tsel  '`

Now I'm wondering whether the default encoding of Log is might not UTF-8 (see file statement) or created query by application is wrong.

Comment: The long lines probably come from long queries.  The confusion over encoding may come from a mixture of encodings.  Can you get a hex dump of `R�tsel` (or some other messed up text)?  For possible insight into the black diamond, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored/38363567 .

Comment: as other variant - redirect general log to table and check